# Send data from Python to PHP script

Tags: php, python

I want to do an HTTP GET request from the Python script to my server. The data I want to send is stored in a variable data.

I am using requests package of python to send it to my PHP page and I am getting the following error

```
import requests
data=850
r=requests.get("http://xxxxx.org/retrieve.php", params= str(data))
```

my retrieve.php file is

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data'])){
$data = $_GET['data'];
echo $data;
 }
else{
     echo "Data not received";
 }
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$f=0;
$data= intval(data);
$sql="select max(ID) from moisture";
$res1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res1);
$ref = $row[0] + 1;
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO moisture VALUES ('$ref' , '$data')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) 
    {       
    $f=1;
    }
else {
     $f=0;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I converted the data to string and then send it. On php script, I am getting the intval of the string but it is storing value '0' instead of '850'

Comment: Try with `urllib` or `requests`

Comment: How you send something to a server depends entirely on how that server is set up to receive information. You need to tell us that.

Comment: @roganjosh I have updated all the details. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, because we cannot see what `payload` looks like. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Payload is a sensor reading ranging from 0 - 1023.

Comment: The most basic post examples involve the use of dictionaries. Your request is choking on an integer. Is it possible that your PHP should be made capable of processing a sensor reading passed as a parameter? Something like `...?sensor=850`

Comment: @BillBell I have updated my PHP code above. I am getting the data and storing it in the database.
I think I am getting the problem in sending the value using the POST method

Comment: Send a get request ( `$_GET['data']` )

Comment: @t.m.adam I tried with GET request. I have updated the error that I am getting in the question

Comment: That's propably a problem with the `data` . Can you include a sample in your post ?

Comment: @t.m.adam I have used static value for data to check the code. 
data=850

Comment: 850 is an int , you can't do that . `data` should be either a dict or a string

Answer (score 0):

My code is working for any static value that I am assigning to it. But it is not sending the data if I am receiving it from the sensor.

```
import serial
import requests
ser=serial.Serial('COM12',9600)
while True:
     data=ser.readline()
     r=requests.get("http://xxxxx.org/retrieve.php", params= data)
```